# Splitting HTML Text Content into Groups while Preserving HTML Layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, formatting

I'm currently wondering about the ability to apply dynamic formatting to content in an HTML page without changing the flow rules.  At face value, this might seem simple, since you can select a subset of the DOM and mass-apply.  However, this would not work if you wanted to apply that formatting to a only one part of the text for a particular object.

For example, formatting:

```
<div>Let's start my format here <span> and here </span> and <br> here too. <br> But not here.</div>
```

If you wanted to exclude `<br> But not here.` from your formatting there is no clear way to do it for the case of an arbitrary layout, even if you did so manually.  One approach is to break the div into span sections, then format them differently.  Unfortunately, wrapping arbitrary HTML in inline elements causes some unfortunate side-effects (e.g., any `<br>` tag in a span will be treated as if it doesn't exist).  Using a block element wrapper, like  introduces similar issues by adding breaks that didn't exist.  I cannot seem to find a way to declare a DOM group that can just plain act as if it were plain text within the parent object.

So then, I'm trying to figure out a good general workaround to introduce display-level formatting while preserving any layout formatting.  This kind of formatting could include text formatting (e.g., highlighting, emphasis) or dynamic effects (e.g., hide/reveal).  I can think of a few hypothetical solutions, but I am not sure what (if any) actually are possible in practice:

1. An existing inline layout element like span that doesn't kill your line breaks and other formatting requests.
2. The ability to make a custom element such as #1 using CSS.  Maybe the run-in or inherit display tags might be useful for this purpose? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)  Neither of them seem like they solve this issue, however.
3. A way to prevent a span from clobbering formatting markup inside of it.
4. A grouping element that acts as a pass-through for layout formatting (i.e., is treated like untagged text for layout purposes) but allows display formatting.

One would think this would be a straightforward thing to do.  After all, it's not hard to imagine wanting to split a div into two different sections that are text-formatted slightly differently, while retaining their layout formatting.  However, I can't seem to find the right tool for this job.

Comment: What's the context?  Is this something you want to be able to do to your own pages, or to other pages? It doesn't sound even a little bit straightforward to me, in any case.

Comment: The context is to use it for annotation purposes.  So the HTML source would be on-hand, but I would be trying to preserve a pre-existing page structure.  In most cases, the approach of wrapping segments of text into a span element works pretty well.  Unfortunately, spans clobber certain HTML tags inside of them, most notably line breaks.

Comment: Well you never know when there might be a CSS rule that does basically anything in the world to `<span>` tags in certain contexts on a page.

Comment: Definitely.  But that's easy enough to fix by just making a custom element that acts like a "default" span but with a name so ridiculous no one would ever use it.

Comment: The more basic issue is that I can't seem to find an HTML element that doesn't seem intent on clobbering the layout one way or another, if all I want is to set look/feel effects.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [LetteringJS](http://letteringjs.com/).  It uses `<span>` tags, as far as I know.

Comment: I think LetteringJS is a bit of overkill.  I may have figured out a custom solution, however.  If it works as expected, I might post it as an answer.  The crux is that if you use a straight HTML parser, you can make sure you only get the plain-text (no formatting tags like <br>), which is appropriate to wrap in span objects.  An inlined text-only span always behaves like straight text, I think, for the purposes of rendering.  But I'll need to keep testing it to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this quite a while, the best that I came up with was to use span wrappers for the **text nodes only**, accompanied by clobbering the default CSS formats for spans.  This had its drawbacks, but thankfully people often leave the basic span class alone.

However, considering it further, I think the best solution is actually to make a new type of span using [webcomponents.js](http://webcomponents.org/) and then to make that span type always inherit the parent formatting.  Particularly if that span type has a very arbitrary name (e.g., `<span-(some guid)/>`), that should be sufficient to prevent any chance of accidental conflict.  I have also found that by wrapping only the text nodes, there is no chance of losing line breaks or other formatting, since those elements can never exist in a text node.

I am not necessarily saying this is the best answer, but it is the best one I've seen so far.